# Inserir variável média (arrays)

Tags: javascript

Preciso inserir a média das duas notas na quarta coluna, como no print abaixo.Alguém poderia me ajudar?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Exemplo 13 - Listagem de Idades</title>

    <style type="text/css">

    </style>

</head>
<h1>Listagem de Notas</h1>
<body>
    <p><label>Digite seu nome:</label><input type="text" id="inNome" size="20"></p>
    <p><label>Digite a nota 1:</label><input type="number" id="nota1"></p>
    <p><label>Digite a nota 2:</label><input type="number" id="nota2"></p>
    <p><input type="button" value="adicionar" onclick="adicionar()">
    <input type="button" value="media" onclick="media()"></p>
    <pre id="resultado"> </pre>

</body>

<script>
    var nomes = []; 
    var notas1 = new Array();
    var notas2 = new Array();
    var media = new Array ();
    var result = document.getElementById("resultado");
    var txtnome = document.getElementById("inNome");
    var txtnota1 = document.getElementById("nota1");
    var txtnota2 = document.getElementById("nota2");
    var txtmedia = ????


    result.textContent = "\nNome\t\tnota1\t\tnota2\t\ttxtmedia";

    function adicionar(){
        nomes.push(txtnome.value);
        notas1.push(txtnota1.value);
        notas2.push(txtnota2.value);
        media.push(txtmedia.value);
        result.textContent += "\n" + txtnome.value + "\t\t" + txtnota1.value + "\t\t" + txtnota2.value + "\t\t" + txtmedia;
    }

</script>

</html>
```

Comment: já tem o valor nas variáveis, então basta converter para número e calcular: `var txtmedia =(Number(textnota1) + Number(txtnota2)) / 2;` veja que, se o valor for decimal e tiver vírgula precisa converter antes, se digitar um valor não numérico também vai dar erro e assim por diante, por isso valide o valor antes, mas basicamente é isso que precisa fazer

Comment: ---- Como o colega explicitou acima, você tem que se atentar ao DOM HTML>

Answer (score 0):

O método `document.getElementById("")` é usado para apanhar uma referência a qualquer elemento em um documento que possua um identificador exclusivo definido para o seu atributo ID.

Esse método é um dos métodos mais comuns no DOM HTML e é usado quase toda vez que você deseja manipular ou **obter informações de um elemento** do documento.

As informações que você deseja somar são os **VALUES** dos inputs ou seja

```
txtmedia = (txtnota1.value) + (txtnota2.value);
```

Só que esses valores, `(apesar dos inputs serem do type number)`, no javascript são considerados do tipo string e portanto não se realizará uma soma e sim uma concatenação.

Observe o exemplo abaixo.

```js
    var result = document.getElementById("resultado");
    var txtnota1 = document.getElementById("nota1");
    var txtnota2 = document.getElementById("nota2");

    
 function testar(){

        console.log(typeof (txtnota1.value));
        console.log(typeof (txtnota2.value));
        
        txtmedia = ((txtnota1.value) + (txtnota2.value));
        
        result.textContent =  "Resultado = " + txtmedia;


    }
```

```html
    <p><label>Digite a nota 1:</label><input type="number" id="nota1"></p>
    <p><label>Digite a nota 2:</label><input type="number" id="nota2"></p>
    <p><input type="button" value="adicionar" onclick="testar()">
    
    <pre id="resultado"> </pre>
```

Assim sendo temos que transformá-los em tipo Number para realizar a operação aritmética.

```
txtmedia = (Number(txtnota1.value) + Number(txtnota2.value))/2
```

Veja o exemplo abaixo

```js
    var result = document.getElementById("resultado");
    var txtnota1 = document.getElementById("nota1");
    var txtnota2 = document.getElementById("nota2");

    
 function testar(){

        console.log(typeof Number(txtnota1.value));
        console.log(typeof Number(txtnota2.value));
        
        txtmedia = (Number(txtnota1.value) + Number(txtnota2.value));
        
        result.textContent =  "Resultado = " + txtmedia;


    }
```

```html
    <p><label>Digite a nota 1:</label><input type="number" id="nota1"></p>
    <p><label>Digite a nota 2:</label><input type="number" id="nota2"></p>
    <p><input type="button" value="adicionar" onclick="testar()">
    
    <pre id="resultado"> </pre>
```

OBS: a operação aritmética (o cálculo da média) deverá ocorrer dentro da função `adicionar()` para que funcione corretamente.

```js
   
    var nomes = []; 
    var notas1 = new Array();
    var notas2 = new Array();
    var media = new Array ();
    var result = document.getElementById("resultado");
    var txtnome = document.getElementById("inNome");
    var txtnota1 = document.getElementById("nota1");
    var txtnota2 = document.getElementById("nota2");

    result.textContent = "\nNome\t\tnota1\t\tnota2\t\ttxtmedia";
    
 function adicionar(){
        nomes.push(txtnome.value);
        notas1.push(txtnota1.value);
        notas2.push(txtnota2.value);
        
        txtmedia = (Number(txtnota1.value) + Number(txtnota2.value))/2;
        
        media.push(txtmedia);
        result.textContent += "\n" + txtnome.value + "\t\t" + txtnota1.value + "\t\t" + txtnota2.value + "\t\t" + txtmedia;
    }
```

```html
    <p><label>Digite seu nome:</label><input type="text" id="inNome" size="20"></p>
    <p><label>Digite a nota 1:</label><input type="number" id="nota1"></p>
    <p><label>Digite a nota 2:</label><input type="number" id="nota2"></p>
    <p><input type="button" value="adicionar" onclick="adicionar()">
    <input type="button" value="media" onclick="media()"></p>
    <pre id="resultado"> </pre>
```